# Dropdown menu not working on safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I have a simple dropdown menu that works on chrome/firefox without any problems, but doesn't work on safari - the menu just doesn't appear on clicking a button:

```
<div>
    <a id='action-btn-1' href='#' data-toggle='dropdown' class='btn btn-default btn-xs edit' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false' role='button'>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu text-left' role='menu' aria-labelledby='dLabel'>
        <li>aaa</li>
        <li>bbb</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What can be possibly wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`role='menu'` is not supported in Safari under a `ul` element.

You need to use a `<select>` elelemt.

Answer (score 0):

Well... you have been using `ARIA` features. I have been following that technology from time to time, just out of interests. Albeit it has to be noted that ARIA is not so widely supported at this moment (February 2017).  You can have a nice overview of browser's support on ARIA features [here](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/1.0/CR/implementation-report#imprep_aria).

But that table is vague and not properly maintained. You have to click on each element to see which row is what... It's not easy to find out which browser supports what.

```
<ul class='dropdown-menu text-left' role='menu' aria-labelledby='dLabel'>
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>bbb</li>
</ul>
```

The problem here is `role='menu'`. You have to check first if Opera supports this. And if so, it could be that they were following the specs more strictly than other browsers (like firefox). Maybe you can try to add the [`menuitem`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#menuitem)-role to verify if that isn't the .

```
<ul class='dropdown-menu text-left' role='menu' aria-labelledby='dLabel'>
    <li role="menuitem">aaa</li>
    <li role="menuitem">bbb</li>
</ul>
```

If it doesn't work, then it may be that Safari doesn't support it *yet*. If that's the situation, you can consider to use a `select` element instead.